# Conditional look-behind (python regex), how to exclude certain words but include certain words?

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I am having trouble creating a python regex string to retrieve only valid places.

Take example the following paragraph with 4 lines:

> Enjoy up to 70% off at New York branches.
>
> Enjoy up to 70% off in Canada.
>
> Not valid at London branches.
>
> Not valid in Germany.

I only want to get the texts of "**New York branches**" and "**Canada**", without getting the "London branches" and "Germany".

This works but it got all the locations:
`((?<=at ).*(?=\.))|((?<=in ).*(?=\.))`

But why this does not work:
`((?<!not )((?<=at ).*(?=\.))|((?<!not )((?<=in ).*(?=\.))`

Specifically: I want all text after the word 'at' or 'in', and before a full stop. However, I do not want them if there is a 'not valid' infront.

Comment: The criteria to select is not very clear. Please explain clearly

Comment: Just skip the lookbehind and use something like this [`^(?!not valid\b).*?(?:at|off).*\.$`](https://regex101.com/r/tR9aI7/1)

Comment: hi @thefourtheye, specifically, I want anything after the word 'at' or 'in', and before a full stop. However, I do not want them if there is a 'not valid' infront.

Comment: hi @HamZa, I've tried your solution, but it doesn't match any of the words...

Comment: Slight tweak of HamZa's regex: https://regex101.com/r/tR9aI7/2

Comment: `^(?!Not valid\b).*(?:at|in)(.*)\.$`

Comment: Are these the only four lines that you intend to use Python regex on? or Do you have many such lines in a large text file? Could you please clarify?

Comment: hi @hypersonics, it is many such lines within a large text file, and each line might not start with 'Not valid', example it could be a text like: Promotion applicable at.....XXX. However, it is not valid at XXXX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer provided by hwnd above is the best way to go

```
^(?!Not valid\b).*(?:at|in)(.*)\.$
```

but to answer your question, what you're trying to accomplish is this

```
(?<=(?<!not valid )(?:at|in) ).*(?=\.)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/229)

Comment: hi @alpha bravo, tested that hwnd's solution works, and yes I was trying to accomplish using lookbehind, however I've tried your 2nd code, it doesn't seem to work for Python Regex, it is still capturing london and germany. http://goo.gl/KLss2t

Comment: ah okay I found the reason, it was due to the lower case 'not' :)